# Vue bootstrap Datalist fix [Object object] displaying?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, tabs, bootstrap-vue

Hey lads is anyone familiar with the datalist from vue bootstrap? Mine is filled from an array as the docs specify but I get weird output...

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post how data looks in `bays` object?

Comment: Thanks ill edit the question now, I want to access just the name but bays.name does not work..

Comment: Bays.value.name doesnt work either :/

Comment: now can you please explain us how the output should look like?

Comment: Can you see if this helps https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form#datalist-helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code

Approach 1:

```
<b-form-datalist id="input-list" :options="baysList"></b-form-datalist>


<script>
   export default {
      computed: {
          baysList() {
              return this.bays.map(x => x.value.name);
          }
      },
      data() {
         return { 
             bays: [],
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

---

Approach 2:

```
<datalist id="input-list">
   <option v-for="bay in bays">{{ bay.value.name }}</option>
</datalist>
```